# Boitum - Need to continue with test scripts when assertion fails for one request and response

Tags: javascript, bots, chatbot, alexa-skills-kit

I have 20 utterance to Alexa .Out of which 1 has assertion error in the middle now I still wish to continue with other utterances in my .Convo file
In practice when we run botium once an assertion fails then the execution stops .

**A sample of error after which my script stopped**

```
Error: News_01/Line 3: error sending to bot Error: Skill simulation for
simulation id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX failed with message: xxxxx
```

> ### I have a list of utterances and response
>
> 1.me:open skillyoga
>
> Alexa:hi joe ,how are you doing today
>
> 2.me:get me exercises on breathing
>
> Alexa: i have 10 types of category .
>
> 3.Me:Not now
>
> 4.Me:Give me list of exercises for increasing concentration
>
> Alexa : we have A exercise and B exercise
>
> Suppose lets say it fails assertion in the 3rd point then the expected result is botium must continue with other test scripts that follows .
>
> This is not the current behaviour in botium

Answer (score 0):

Botium is about test automation: as soon as a single step of the test case is failed, the whole test case is failed (and the whole test suite).

It seems as if your are trying to pack multiple test cases into one BotiumScript, while there should be several of them:

test case 1:

```
#me
open skillyoga

#bot
hi joe, how are you doing today
```

test case 2:

```
#me
get me exercises on breathing

#bot
i have 10 types of category

#me
not now

#bot
...
```

test case 3:

```
#me
Give me list of exercises for increasing concentration

#bot
we have A exercise and B exercise
```

Comment: So if i have 10 request and 10 response from alexa .Then each must be kept as a separate convo file so even if one fails then the next convo file will be took and run .Am i right. "one.convo.txt" this will have one request and response ."two.convo.txt" this will have another request and response .Is my understanding correct

Comment: yes correct. For just Question/Answer style conversations, maybe CSV is the better format to use: https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/48463903/Composing+in+CSV+files

Comment: thanks a lot it worked .I'm able to run test scripts independently even when one script fails the others seems to run